# What is the difference between googDecodeMs and googMaxDecodeMs?

Tags: webrtc

The best I can figure is that `googDecodeMs` is the instantaneous decode time when `getStats()` is called, and `googMaxDecodeMs` is the maximum amount of time it took to decode video since the last `getStats()` call.

Example:

```
googDecodeMs: 0
googDecodeMs: 197
googDecodeMs: 133
googDecodeMs: 165
googDecodeMs: 132
googDecodeMs: 127
googDecodeMs: 90
googDecodeMs: 36
googDecodeMs: 65
googDecodeMs: 71
googDecodeMs: 15
googDecodeMs: 18
googDecodeMs: 19
googDecodeMs: 5
googDecodeMs: 6
googDecodeMs: 3
googDecodeMs: 16
```

```
googMaxDecodeMs: 0
googMaxDecodeMs: 298
googMaxDecodeMs: 279
googMaxDecodeMs: 263
googMaxDecodeMs: 241
googMaxDecodeMs: 230
googMaxDecodeMs: 199
googMaxDecodeMs: 188
googMaxDecodeMs: 166
googMaxDecodeMs: 146
googMaxDecodeMs: 134
googMaxDecodeMs: 103
googMaxDecodeMs: 93
googMaxDecodeMs: 83
googMaxDecodeMs: 83
googMaxDecodeMs: 61
googMaxDecodeMs: 33
```

Comment: not all frames are alike, some take more time to decode than others. If you still rely on those "legacy" goog-proprietary stats which are not documented you should be aware they will go away soon: https://groups.google.com/g/discuss-webrtc/c/EmcOEY2gj6w/m/EcTFK_cQAgAJ

Comment: Interesting. So is `googDecodeMs` the mean and `googMaxDecodeMs` is the max?

Comment: That's so much nicer than what exists today.